# Can I show a MessageBox but still use the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

It is possible that when I use:

```
MessageBox.Show("hello");
```

..to still use the form but the MessageBox is open like a second window?
because currently, when I show the MessageBox, I need to first click yes or no then I can use my form again.

Comment: You can make your own message box form and display that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, you can!

If you simply want to display a MessageBox, don't care what happens with it, and don't want to wait until it's closed, you may launch it on a separate thread. The easiest way to do that would be using [`Task.Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run).

Here's an example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show("hello"));

    // The remaining code will run without waiting for the MessageBox to be closed.
}
```

**A couple of notes worth mentioning:**

- Only use this for simple message boxes where you don't care about the result. If you want to act based on the result and execute something (on the main thread), things get a little bit trickier.
- You won't be able to keep the MessageBox on top of the form. Once you interact with the form, it will come on top. If you need to keep the MessageBox on top and still have the ability to interact with the form, a custom MessageBox (i.e., form) would be better in that case because you can set the [`Owner` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.owner) to keep it on top.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The application focus remains on the Message Box until it is dismissed.  According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox):

> It is a modal window, blocking other actions in the application until the user closes it.

What you *can* do is create your own form, style it to look like a standard Message Box, and show that form using the `.Show()` functionality on an instance of it:

```
var messageBox = new MyCustomMessageBox("hello");
messageBox.Show();
```

---

If you want the functionality to be identical in usage, you could even add a `static` method to your custom form which encapsulates it:

```
public static void Show(string message)
{
    new MyCustomMessageBox(message).Show();
}
```

Though what I wouldn't recommend doing is calling your custom form `MessageBox`, that would just be asking for confusion.

Comment: oh. okay, it is possible to override the method that blocks other actions?

Comment: @AleaLindemann: It's not clear what you mean, or how that's different from what you asked in the question above.  Can you clarify?

Comment: of course. I mean to override the focus. to disable the blocking. instead of making a custom messagebox

Comment: @AleaLindemann: As indicated above... No.  The application focus remains on the Message Box until it is dismissed. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox): *"It is a modal window, blocking other actions in the application until the user closes it."*

Comment: @david David while trying to implement your solution I got some errors. I'm using .Net Core 3.1.7. https://imgur.com/a/hevR3QA

Comment: @TheLeb: That was a typo on my part.  I've udpated the answer.  The static `Show` method needs a return type.  In this case `void` would work fine.